# Query taxonomy term for given product

Tags: entities, taxonomy-terms, commerce

I have a node template, rendering a product list based on a query :

```
$productsQuery = db_select('commerce_product', 'p');
$productsQuery->join('commerce_product_type', 't', 't.type = p.type');

$productsQuery->fields('p')
    ->fields('t')
    ->condition('p.status', 0, '>')
    ->orderBy('p.created', 'DESC')
;

$results = $productsQuery->execute()->fetchAll();

foreach ($results as $product) {
    $productNodeQuery = new EntityFieldQuery();
    $productNodeQuery->entityCondition('entity_type', 'node', '=')
        ->propertyCondition('type', $product->type)
        ->fieldCondition('field_product', 'product_id', $product->product_id, '=')
        ->range(0, 1);

    if ($node = $productNodeQuery->execute()) {
        $node = array_shift($node['node']);
        // Render the node
    }
}
```

It is working well, but I do not access to the different fields of the product-display node in EntityFieldQuery...

For instance, In my product-display, I have a required relation to a taxonomy term, that I would like to display for each product.

How to get this specific field ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An `EntityFieldQuery` just returns IDs, you need to load the entities manually:

```
$results = $query->execute();
if (!empty($results['node'])) {
  $nodes = node_load_multiple(array_keys($results['node'));
  foreach ($nodes as $node) {
    if ($items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_foo')) {
      // ...
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay thanks, I am trying ;

Just wondering, do I have to do it after the EntityFieldQuery ?
Isn't it a huge leak of performances to have to execute 2 additional queries for each product ?

Comment: Yep, welcome to Drupal :) You can only query one entity type at a time with `EntityFieldQuery`; you can filter by field, but it has to be a 'real' field (e.g. not a reverse entity-reference), so you can't get all the commerce products with the reverse reference to the display node in one query - it has to be done twice, and I think (API-wise at least) that's the quickest way

Comment: Okay thanks again ! The field_get_items() always returns me "false", I think I am confusing about the field name (3rd argument), but I am pretty sure it is "field_category"...
How/Where can I check the name ?

Comment: Easiest way is through the UI - if you go to Admin -> Structure -> Content Types -> Type -> Manage Fields, you can see the field name

Comment: I am affraid that my product display is a product-variation-type, more than a content-type... Could it be the reason why I can't find my type ? How to do it properly, otherwise ?

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you mean. You mentioned the field was attached to the product display content type, that should be where you find it. Commerce doesn't enforce a particular name for the product display type, so it'll either be the default (product_display), or whatever you've set it up as. You can see that by editing the content type and looking for the machine name...

Comment: The problem is that I have the machine name, but it's not working ; It seems that my product-variation-type is not synchronised with the content-type of same machine name...
For instance, I have a variation-type called "vine".

The content-type : admin/structure/types/manage/vine/fields does not have the same fields that the product-variation-type : admin/commerce/config/product-variation-types/vine/fields...

Is it normal ?